# Invalid password causing infinite display loop

Tags: c++

I am creating a function that checks the user's username and password. When I enter the username and password correctly, the program outputs the correct string. Then, when I enter the incorrect username OR password, the correct **while** loop is output. However, when I try to enter the correct username after the **while** loop, I get an infinite loop of my while loop contents.

What is causing this infinite loop when entering the username a second time?

Here is the function I am working on:

```
void CheckUserPermissionAccess()
{

    int userPassInput;
    string usernameInput;

    string user1 = "Bob Jones";
    string user2 = "Sarah Davis";
    string user3 = "Amy Friendly";
    string user4 = "Johnny Smith";
    string user5 = "Carol Spears";


    int BobPass = 9874;
    int SarahPass = 3478;
    int AmyPass = 2991;
    int JohnnyPass = 5503;
    int CarolPass = 2814;

    cout << "Enter your username: " << endl;
    getline(cin, usernameInput); 
    cout << "Enter your password: " << endl;
    cin >> userPassInput;


    if (usernameInput == user1 && userPassInput == BobPass)
    {
        cout << "password accepted" << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if (usernameInput == user2 && userPassInput == SarahPass)
    {
        cout << "password accepted" << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        while (usernameInput != user1 || userPassInput != BobPass)
        {
            cout << "Invalid Username or Password. Please try again" << endl;
            cout << "Enter your username: " << endl;
            getline(cin, usernameInput);
            cout << "Enter your password: " << endl;
            cin >> userPassInput;
        }
    }

    return;

}
```

Here is a small part of the infinite loop that gets displayed after entering the username a second time:

```
Invalid Password. Please try again
Enter your username: 
Enter your password: 
Invalid Password. Please try again
Enter your username: 
Enter your password: 
Invalid Password. Please try again
Enter your username: 
Enter your password: 
Invalid Password. Please try again
Enter your username: 
Enter your password: 
Invalid Password. Please try again
Enter your username: 
Enter your password: 
Invalid Password. Please try again
```

Comment: Because your previous `enter` press is in the input as `\n` as well but you never ignore or clear it it. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21567292/4123703).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer according to your code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<limits>
using namespace std;

void CheckUserPermissionAccess()
{

    int userPassInput;
    string usernameInput;

    string user1 = "Bob Jones";
    string user2 = "Sarah Davis";
    string user3 = "Amy Friendly";
    string user4 = "Johnny Smith";
    string user5 = "Carol Spears";


    int BobPass = 9874;
    int SarahPass = 3478;
    int AmyPass = 2991;
    int JohnnyPass = 5503;
    int CarolPass = 2814;

    cout << "Enter your username: " << endl;
    getline(cin, usernameInput); 
    cout << "Enter your password: " << endl;
    cin >> userPassInput;


    if (usernameInput == user1 && userPassInput == BobPass)
    {
        cout << "password accepted" << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if (usernameInput == user2 && userPassInput == SarahPass)
    {
        cout << "password accepted" << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        
        while (usernameInput != user1 || userPassInput != BobPass)
        {
            cout << "Invalid Username or Password. Please try again" << endl;
            cout << "Enter your username: " << endl;
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
            getline(cin, usernameInput);
            cout << "Enter your password: " << endl;
            cin >> userPassInput;
        }
    }

    return;

}


int main(){
    CheckUserPermissionAccess();
}
```

You can also read [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/clearing-the-input-buffer-in-cc/) for your better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ignore the rest of the current line after the usage of `std::cin`, up to `EOF` or `'\n'` – so that the earlier input is cleared. This problem can be easily fixed by adding two lines:

```
#include <limits>

void function() {
   .
   while(.) {
       cin.clear();
       cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
       .
       .
   }
}
```

I've got these output:

```
Enter your username: 
Bob
Enter your password: 
123

Invalid Username or Password. Please try again
Enter your username: 
Bob Jones
Enter your password: 
9874
```

Comment: Hello Rohan, I am a little new to this, so should I add the cin.clear() and cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); into my else statement?

Comment: @ZaneBrown Add this at the beginning of the `while()`.